# Do you make your own impulse responses?

Tags: convolution, convolution-reverb, impulse-response, reaktor, sound-designer

I'm not referring to actual rooms, i'm talking more about weirdness. I've been trying to use Skanner XT in reaktor (i mean, it can be any synth for that matter) to make some custom weird IRs. I'm getting some mixed results. A lot of the time it sounds like the same synth sound through reverb.

Any good tips on doing that sort of thing? My reverb is either Space Designer, Kontakt built in convolution, or Reflektor. Not that it really matters, once again.

Comment: Try contrasting the IR signal and the signal that will be convoluted. I.e. they should have very different frequency responses, and also dynamics and loudness, to emphasize the difference that results when one is convoluted with the other. Similar to vocoding, it matters a lot what your "modulating" i.e. the IR signal is and how it's characteristics affect the sound the IR is applied to.

Answer (score 1):

The quality of the convolution can depend on a lot of factors. IRs are meant to sample a space over time. With something like a synth, the change of frequency content over time would probably be less important (compared to a reverb). I have found that chopping the length of the sample to a few milliseconds (or tens or hundreds of milliseconds) can result in better results ;) . This is quite easy to do in Space Designer, without needing to edit the source file.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. I recently wrote an article on this very subject which details creation of an impulse response to simulate a "radio" effect in a signal chain.

http://www.greensideproductions.com.au/2013/01/04/creating-a-radio-effect-using-a-convolution-filter/

enjoy.